# Uncaught Reference Error in Duda Widget Builder. Html/JS

Tags: javascript

My code gives me the following error for the first function:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

I also get this error for the second function:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: filterFunction is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

I checked for answers and the most commonly given was "Select No wrap - bottom of `<head>` in the "Load type" dropdown in the JavaScript settings."

I cant select this since I'm using a Duda widget builder and no classic development environment.  Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks a lot.

```js
function myFunction() {
 document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show"); // Klicken zeigt bzw. verbirgt die Dropdown Liste 
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log(ele.value);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown3">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Bereich</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#pflege">Pflege</a>
    <a href="#verwaltung">Verwaltung</a>
    <a href="#gastro">Gastronomie</a>
    <a href="#wäsche">Wäscherei</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Rory. I just did the first of your solutions. I declared the functions like this "window.myFunction = function() {
    // .... code ....
}"
But now I get the following Error " Uncaught (in promise) Error: cannot call methods on resizable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'
    at Function.error (jquery.min.js:2)"

Answer (score 0):

The fix you've found only applies to code executed in a https://jsfiddle.net demo.

In your case you have two fixes you can use. The first is to make the two functions globally scoped. This is why the `onX` attributes can't find them currently, they're out of scope.

The other, and far better, approach, is to get rid of the `onX` attributes from your HTML entirely and use unobtrusive event handlers. Here's an example of how to do that:

```js
document.querySelector('.dropbtn').addEventListener('click', function() { 
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
})

document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  let filter = this.value.toUpperCase();
  let div = document.querySelector("#myDropdown");
  let a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    let txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    console.log(this.value);
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="dropdown3">
  <button class="dropbtn">Bereich</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" />
    <a href="#pflege">Pflege</a>
    <a href="#verwaltung">Verwaltung</a>
    <a href="#gastro">Gastronomie</a>
    <a href="#wäsche">Wäscherei</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thanks I overlooked this and will try it immediately.

Comment: You too. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Comment: Yes thank you Rory you are very helpful ! Have a nice day !